# How to scale multiple faces proportionally

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am making a leather sofa texture. I need help. As you can see in the animated image below I want to extrude the edges from all sides.

I have press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to make it proportional on all sides. How do I scale all sides at same time?

[image]

Comment: You forgot to attach the image you mentioned.

Comment: sorry i forgot to attach the image now its uploaded

Comment: What does the geometry you try to achieve look like in the end? Could you post a screenshot of one area, like before <-> after? I don't yet get what you're up to.

Comment: im making leather sofa and the extrude and scale is made at the center and not to side right and left may i know y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, then select <kbd>Region (Vertex Normals)</kbd>.

[image: region vertex normals extrude]

Comment: im getting some other results